# How can I capture mouse click and drag events for a MapControl in react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

In `react-leaflet`, I implemented a `MapControl` which contains a slider.

But, dragging it also drags the map. How can I disable dragging of the map when I'm interacting with my `MapControl`?

My control:

```
class MapDateSlider extends MapControl {
  createLeafletElement(props) {
    const control = L.control({ position: 'bottomleft' })
    const jsx = (
            <DateSlider {...props} />
    )
    control.onAdd = () => {
      const div = L.DomUtil.create('div', '')
      ReactDOM.render(jsx, div)
      return div
    }
    return control
  }
}


export default withLeaflet(MapDateSlider)
```

Question is very similar to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104507/disable-panning-dragging-on-leaflet-map-for-div-within-map) but specific to react-leaflet, not pure leaflet.

I've tried adding events to the control in the same way `onAdd` is added, like:

```
    control.onMouseOver = () => {
      console.log('mouseover')
      props.leaflet.map.dragging.disable()
    }
    control.onMouseOut = () => {
      console.log('mouseout')
      props.leaflet.map.dragging.enable()
    }
```

but they never fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, I added the `onMouseOut` and `onMouseOver` listeners to a div wrapping the component:

```js
class MapDateSlider extends MapControl {
  createLeafletElement(props) {
    const control = L.control({ position: 'bottomleft' })
    const jsx = (
      <div
        onMouseOver={() => {
          props.leaflet.map.dragging.disable()
        }}
        onMouseOut={() => {
          props.leaflet.map.dragging.enable()
        }}
      >            
            <DateSlider {...props} />
      </div>
    )
    control.onAdd = () => {
      const div = L.DomUtil.create('div', '')
      ReactDOM.render(jsx, div)
      return div
    }
    return control
  }
}


export default withLeaflet(withStyles(eventsPageStyle)(MapDateSlider))
```